# Celery active tasks persistence

Tags: celery, persistence

If celery crashes during executing some task, this task is lost after restart celery. Tasks that in the queue in the moment of the crash, will be restored fine in RabbitMQ. But how can I make active tasks persistent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Celery is configured by default with `task_acks_late=False`. [1] This means that the task is acked as soon as the worker receives it from the queue. And if the task fails, the queue has no way of knowing it.

Set `task_acks_late` to `True` and the task will be acked **after** it has been processed. When the task fails, it is requeued. [2] But be careful, **your tasks must be idempotent**. [3]

- [1] http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_acks_late
- [2] http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#faq-acks-late-vs-retry
- [3] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence